Combinatorial proof of $k(n-k) \le \binom nk - 1.$
It is known that two lists of $k$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k$ and $w_1, \dots, w_k$ from an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ span the same subspace if and only if $v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k = \lambda w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_k$  for some scalar $\lambda \ne 0.$ This produces the Plücker embedding from the manifold consisting of all linear subspaces of $V$ of dimension $k$ (the grassmanian) to the projective space $P(\Lambda^k(V)).$ Comparing the dimensions,
$$k(n-k) \le \binom nk - 1.$$
I am looking for a direct combinatorial proof of this inequality, for integers $0 \le k \le n.$

After some thought I have come up with the proof I was looking for. Choose disjoint sets $A, C$ of $k, n-k$ elements respectively. The number $\binom nk-1$ counts the number of ways to choose $k$ white elements and $n-k$ black elements of $A \cup C$, such that at least one element of $A$ is black (equivalently, at least one element of $C$ is white).
Given an element $(a, c) \in A \times C,$ we can let $a$ be the only black element of $A$; also, let $c$ be the only white element of $C$. This is a valid assignment of colors, and it's different for each choice of $(a, c).$ Since $A\times C$ has $k(n-k)$ elements, we have
$$k(n-k) \le \binom nk -1$$
as desired.

I wouldn't use $B$ and $w$ for the set names when it is not the same as the black-white colored sets, it made me confused for a moment.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks, I hope it's less confusing now.

This is similar to an argument I made: choose k numbers from 1,2,...,n such that your choice is not 1,2,...,k. There are $$\binom{n}{k} - 1$$ total ways to do this. On the other hand, choosing all but one of the numbers from 1,...,k and one from k+1,...,n is a subset of that and can be done in $$\binom{k}{k-1}\binom{n-k}{1}=k(n-k)$$ ways.
